# Why does gdb get wrong "optind" variable value?

Tags: c, gdb, getopt

I am writing a simple program which using `getopt` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        char *fname;
        int c;

        printf("Before getopt: optind is %d, address is %p \n", optind, &optind);

        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
                switch (c) {
                case 'f':
                        fname = optarg;
                        break;
                }

        printf("After getopt: optind is %d, address is %p \n", optind, &optind);
        return 0;
}
```

Executing it, outputs:

```
# ./test -f 1
Before getopt: optind is 1, address is 0x601040
After getopt: optind is 3, address is 0x601040
```

But when using `gdb` to debug it, some weird things happen:

```
13              printf("Before getopt: optind is %d, address is %p \n", optind, &optind);
(gdb) n
Before getopt: optind is 1, address is 0x601040
15              while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "f:")) != -1)
(gdb) p &optind
$1 = (int *) 0x7ffff7dd42a0 <optind>
(gdb) n
16                      switch (c) {
(gdb) n
18                              fname = optarg;
(gdb)
19                              break;
(gdb) p &optind
$2 = (int *) 0x7ffff7dd42a0 <optind>
(gdb) p optind
$3 = 1
```

I can see using `p optind` command, it outputs `1` (should be `3`), and this variable address is `0x7ffff7dd42a0`, not `0x601040`.

Using `readelf` command:

```
# readelf -a test | grep optind
000000601040  000600000005 R_X86_64_COPY     0000000000601040 optind + 0
 6: 0000000000601040     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 optind@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
54: 0000000000601040     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 optind@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

It also display one `optind`, and its address should be `0x601040`. So when using `gdb`, why does it get `optind` from `0x7ffff7dd42a0`? What is it?

**Update**:
Using the newest `gdb 7.11`, and find this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [obscure gdb bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=8588), triggered by another obscure feature known as a copy relocation.

Comment: just using the newest `gdb 7.11`, and find this issue has been fixed.